# how to check DKIM signatures in emails

Tags: email, spam

I'm looking for a gmail-compatible app that can check DKIM signatures on incoming emails.
Also, i'd like my outgoing emails to be signed correctly, so they are less likely to be filtered as spam...

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/180707